# Many to many relationship detecting changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to understand why DbContext doesn't detect changesin many-to-many relationship. This is what I have set in model configuration:

```
this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

This is the test code:

```
var book = Context.Set<Book>().Where(b => b.Id == 1).Single();
var author = Context.Set<Author>().Where(a => a.Id == 2).Single();

book.Authors.Add(author);
```

if I check for changes, it doesn't report any:

```
// returns false
_context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

If I save changes, changes are updated to database correctly.

```
// 1 record added to BookAuthors table
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Why is DbContext not tracking changes for many-to-many? WCF is not involved, this is a direct connection to Sql server.

Comment: There's a very good explanation here [Many to Many relationships change tracking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490509/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-change-tracking)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DbContext` is not tracking changes because `ChangeTracker` doesn't hold all information. It is able to give you only state of entities but not state of independent associations (that is state of many-to-many and some one-to-many relations). If you want to get state of many-to-many relation you must get `ObjectContext` and ask `ObjectStateManager` as described in the link provided by @Mark Oreta.