# Manually update collections modified status in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having some trouble adding or removing relationships from an entity with `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` set.  Example models and code are as follows:

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile : Entity
{
    public Guid UserProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var context = new OfContext();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

var userProfile = context.UserProfiles
                         .Include(up => up.Categories)
                         .FirstOrDefault(up => up.UserProfileId == new Guid("XXXX"));
var category = context.Categories
                      .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == new Guid("XXXX"));

userProfile.Categories.Add(category);
userProfile.Name = "Updated";
context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

The issue I am having is the addition of the category to the collection is not saved with  `SaveChanges`. If I have `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true`, this change is picked up and persisted.  So I guess the real question is, how do I manually indicate that this collection has been modified.

I know that for properties, I can use the following

```
.Property(u => u.Name).IsModified
```

But I am not seeing anything similar to indicate a collection has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` to do it, EF will check if entries are changed, and the mark then to be persited in database, so you just mush change this method before `SaveChanges`, se the code:

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile : Entity
{
    public Guid UserProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var context = new OfContext();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Include(up => up.Categories).FirstOrDefault(up => up.UserProfileId == new Guid("XXXX"));
var category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == new Guid("XXXX"));
userProfile.Categories.Add(category);
userProfile.FirstName = "Updated";
context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case, you could also remove that line

```
context.Entry(userProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

If you wont use DetectChanges method, you can use ObjectStateManager in this way

```
var context = new OfContext();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.Include(up => up.Categories).FirstOrDefault(up => up.UserProfileId == new Guid("XXXX"));
var category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == new Guid("XXXX"));
userProfile.Categories.Add(category);
userProfile.FirstName = "Updated";
var objectStateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
objectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(userProfile, category, x => x.Categories, EntityState.Added);
objectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(userProfile, EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This line

`objectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(userProfile, EntityState.Modified);`

Will handle the modification of FirstName property, and any other simple property.

And this line

```
objectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(userProfile, category, x => x.Categories, EntityState.Added);
```

Will handle the relationship modification of Categories property.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that does seem to work but is there any way to set that state manually (Similar to the Entry().State) so that the call to DetectChanges() is not needed?  Presumably it is setting the state of something so that SaveChanges() knows what to update.  Again thanks for the info.

Comment: @Domtar Why are you running out from DetectChanges? Why do you need do it manually?

Comment: @Domtar I changed the answer to fit your question, without use DectectChanges.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the info.  In terms of the AutoDetectChanges, we are importing a large number of relationships and the Repository we are using (genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com) has us manually setting status for stuff anyway.  So Many-Many relationships where the only thing that where not manually set.  I figured why go through all the other detect changes code if I was already setting the status for 90% of the changes.  Thanks for the great response.

Comment: @Domtar Np, sadly that isn't useful either correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChangeTracker` class doesn't hold all data about the state of your model. It contains only data about states of the entities but not about the state of independent associations such as many-to-many relationships (as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699892/many-to-many-relationship-detecting-changes))

These changes are tracked in the `ObjectStateManager` class. You should be able to mark a relationship between two entities as changed with the `ChangeRelationshipState` method (see [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487266(v=vs.110).aspx))

*Sidenote* - to get the `ObjectStateManager` for a `DbContext`, it is necessary to cast the `DbContext` to the `ObjectContext`

```
var objectStateManager = 
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbcontext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```